# Animated(.swf) image is the top layer of the webpage, Why?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am trying to use an .swf animated image on my Home page. And its acting weird. All the popups show underneath the animated image. I dont understand why? How can i make it stick to the page , and not be on top of popups, etc.   This is done using html, javascript, asp.net.

This is how i have used the animated image on the webpage. I hope i am clear

```
 <div id="divmarquee" runat="server" style="text-align:center">
  <object width="475px" height="75px">
     <embed src="merchant_images/The_Marquee_Deal.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="475px" height="75px"></embed>
     </object> 
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash likes to overlap everything on a web page by default.  You need to include these attributes in your embed tag to ensure that it behaves properly:

```
style="z-index: 0" wmode="transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likley it is caused by "Windowed" mode set in the flash itself by default - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_window_mode.html for defineition, for more detail - http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=E5141. You can try to set "wmode" to overrride the default.